# In QT5, How to close a QTextList added using QTextCursor so I can add regular text after it.

Tags: qt, pyqt, qt5, pyqt5, qtextedit

I'm using PyQT, QTextEdit. I would like to create a list, add a few items, close the list, and add some more regular text.

I've managed to create the list and add items with:

```
#self is a subclass of QTextEdit
cursor = self.textCursor()
cursor.insertList(QTextListFormat())
cursor.insertText('item 1')
cursor.insertText('item 2')
```

But i can not find how to close that list.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and given that Qt is usually very intuitive and easy to use I was surprised that there seems to be no easy way to do it. begin/endEditBlock() didn't work for me. I've finally found `QTextFormat::ListFormat` which let me came up with following solution (in C++ but it should be easy to translate to Python):

```
void AddList(QTextCursor* cursor, const QStringList& list_items) {
  QTextList* list = nullptr;
  QTextBlockFormat non_list_format = cursor->blockFormat();
  for (const auto& list_item : list_items) {
    if (!list) {
      list = cursor->insertList(QTextListFormat::ListDisc);
    } else {
      cursor->insertBlock();
    }
    cursor->insertText(list_item);
  }
  // This ends the list.
  cursor->insertBlock();
  cursor->setBlockFormat(non_list_format);
}
```